# Magento 2 link youtube videos to products

Tags: magento2, product, product-video, youtube

I know in Magento 2.3, we can able to link youtube videos with products. At the end of the youtube video, I can see the suggested video thumbnails in it.

**Is there any way to remove the suggested videos thumbnail at the end of the youtube video?**

Answer (score 0):

I think the Magento 2 by default have the option to remove the related videos from product linked videos,

You have to Set "**No**" for the configuration **Admin->Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Product Video->Show related video**. Check the below screenshot.

[image]

Clear the cache and check, I Hope this will work fo you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. The following configuration is set as No.
Still the youtube videos are showing suggested videos at the end.
It is not working in Magento 2.3.4